# columns inside column tag colgroup

Tags: html

I'm trying to generate a table in a template using the colgroup tag, but I can not understand how to create columns inside a column.

For exemple:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <colgroup class="span12">
        <col class="span1">
        <col class="span1">
        <col class="span1">
        <col class="span1">
        <col class="span1">
        <col class="span1">
        <col class="span1">
        <colgroup class="span5">
            <col class="span1">
            <col class="span1">
            <col class="span1">
            <col class="span1">
            <col class="span1">
            <col class="span1">
            <col class="span1">
        </colgroup>
    </colgroup>
```

I used to sold this with this logic before, but this seens not work with colgroup tag:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-8
      .col-md-6
        | content
      .col-md-6
        | content
    .col-md-4
      .col-md-12
        | content
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables in HTML can exclusively be created and populated by rows. The colgroup and col elements are used to apply styles to columns. This is not an ideal way of styling columns, as I would prefer to target `:nth-child(#)` inside `<tr>` elements. Now you could "transform" a table's `<tr>`s into columns by saying:

```
table td{
    display: block;
}
table tr {
    display: table-cell;
}
```